# Angular2 providers

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

I am not fully grasping providers and can't figure this one out. I have a class with a constructor as so:

`constructor(private http:Http, private url:string, private ext:string){}`

Within the bootstrap how do I tell the DI to supply the Http but then use two variables: `environment.url` and `environment.ext` to supply the strings?

I know that I need to use providers but it wont accept the token *string* and I need to specify multiple times and only in the case of my class, not globally.

**Note:**
I know I can just import `environment.url` and `environment.ext` within my class but I want to have those two parameters set via constructor to minimize dependencies.

Comment: set it on global level like at the time of bootstrap of your app ?

Comment: I dont follow, can you please demo it for me?

Comment: i mean like other PROVIDERS you also can set local variable and method globally so that this can be available throughout whole app. i hope you get it ?

Comment: No I am not. I dont want it to be injected or care from what object it comes from. I just want to be able to pass two strings into the constructor and save them.

Comment: yes i am jss suggesting

Comment: Can you please just write an example? I dont understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118469/discussion-between-zaksback-and-pardeep-jain).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would probably be to wrap the two into a class and supply the class as a provider.  Injecting strings is somewhat difficult (although possible).  If you want to do that then read up on the section titled **Non-class dependencies** in the [dependency injection guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html).

Alternatively, if you want the path of least resistance.

```
//environment-config.ts
export class EnvironmentConfig {
    constructor(public url:string, ext:string);
}

//main.ts (or wherever you call bootstrap)
config:EnvironmentConfig = {url:"foo", ext:"bar"};
bootstrap(RootComponent, [ config, HTTP_PROVIDERS, disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()]);

//foo.component.ts
constructor(private http:Http, private config:EnvironmentConfig);
```

Comment: Also, note that many frameworks and seed projects (e.g. webpack starter project) have mechanisms for supplying environment configuration that changes between development & production and you may want to tie into that.  There is no standard angular2 solution as far as I know.